# adding a column with sequence data to table based on repeating events

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL (via mode) and am approaching the Advanced section. I have a dataset that contains events that recur and I want to add a column that identifies the first, second, third, fourth, etc (no limit) occurrence of the events for that day.

```
CustomerID     ActivityType     Day     Sequence
Adam           Inquiry          1       1
Barb           Inquiry          1       2
Adam           Inquiry          1       3
Charlie        Inquiry          1       4
Barb           Order            1       5
Charlie        Inquiry          1       6
Adam           Inquiry          1       7
Barb           Order            1       8
```

I've searched here for problems that seem similar, to help focus my learning but I don't see anything quite the same.

My desired output would be the same as above but with an added column that shows the sequence of recurring combinations of customer and activity, like this:

```
CustomerID     ActivityType     Day     Sequence  Recur
Adam           Inquiry          1       1         1
Barb           Inquiry          1       2         1
Adam           Inquiry          1       3         2
Charlie        Inquiry          1       4         1
Barb           Order            1       5         1
Charlie        Inquiry          1       6         2
Adam           Inquiry          1       7         3
Barb           Order            1       8         2
```

Comment: I would suggest that you refrain from storing derived data. Just calculate the recurrence at run-time

Comment: My intention to store is that the data is always unchanging (historical) and I would export to Excel for others to review, and they would want to filter on the recur field.

Comment: I would build it into the export query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can simply use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` for that purpose:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerID, ActivityType ORDER BY Sequence) recur
FROM mytable t
```

Note: As commented by Strawberry, storing that information in a additional column does not make a lot of sense, because it can be complicated to maintain: for example, if your table is updated, you will potentially need to recompute the whole column. You would better compute the information on the fly when querying the table.

Comment: This is super-helpful, pointing me to learn specifically about window functions. I will dig in there and continue, and also avoid the "storing in the database" error, which must seem really "newbie" I imagine. Thanks to both of you!